# ASP.NET Charting Control currency formatting

Tags: asp.net, formatting, charts

I need to use a different currency for my Y Axis labels. I read http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/56453466-06b1-4df4-8265-5c63dc18efe5/ but I'm still battling to change the dollar sign to a different char.

Answer (score 2):

In the FormatNumber event:

```
if (e.ElementType == DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.AxisLabels)
{
    System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo nfi = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
    nfi.CurrencySymbol = "#";
    e.LocalizedValue = string.Format(nfi, e.Format, e.Value);
}
```